# two spring apps coomunicating through a database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

I have a spring app that will be adding to a database, and from the other side, I want to monitor if the database is changed so I do some statistics about the new changes and send them to another db, how I can do that...

thank you.

I thought about KAFKA but I'm not sure if it can be used here.

Comment: perhaps triggers are an option https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger, depending on the db it's possible to call java code... or just polling

Comment: Yes Kafka can be used here. After successful insertion you notify Kafka. Say dataUpdate topic for example. then the second app could listen to that topic.

Comment: As said in earlier comments, Kafka could be used, but if you don't need Kafka for anything else, it's overkill. If you do not already have a Kafka cluster set up, then you might just want to send a http request to the second application. Basically, any kind of message/messaging system would work if you just want to inform the second system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need an Outbox Microservices Pattern: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html

Answer (score 0):

Although all the solutions provided in the comments will work in my view [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) is a very good way to go. More than this if you have a Kafka cluster available then you could make use of the out of the box [Debezium Kafka Connectors](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/) with support for the most popular databases such as Oracle, SqlSever, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc